# How to make a Button thats gives output the Selected Seats Array

Tags: javascript

How to make a button that takes all the selected seats(By Class Name .selected) and return the id's of them in an array.
Example:[image: Cinema]

I try this but doens't work for multi seats,1 by 1 only.

```
 const tick = document.querySelector(".row__seat--selected").dataset.tooltip;
console.log(tick);

//Stringify the Array
const myJSON = JSON.stringify(tick);
console.log(myJSON);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elementIDs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.row__seat--selected'),
function (cookie) {return cookie.id;});
console.log(elementIDs);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use different selector - `document.querySelectorAll()`

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
console.log([...nodeList].map(i => i.attributes.id.value))
```

```html
<div class="selected" id='first'>1 selected</div>
<div class="not-selected">not selected</div>
<div class="selected" id='second'>2 selected</div>
<div class="not-selected">not selected</div>
<div class="selected" id="third">3 selected</div>
```

Comment: if i go with selectorall i have problem with dataset.tooltip

Comment: Can i just don't use thats,and go with a new onClick function that give's me all the IDs of The Selected?

Comment: becasue instead of single object you will have array of objects

Comment: Ok,but if i need only onclick the array of the ids?

Comment: each object should have ID of the selected element - you can simply modify array from document.querySelectorAll() to array of ids via `map` method

Comment: const tick = document.querySelectorAll(".row__seat--selected");
returns me NodeList

Comment: So ,eventually if i want a simple button, that onclickfunction :Get the Selected seats by class name .selected & reuturns the IDs of the seats? Can't do that?

Comment: you have all needed information there

Comment: look carrefully at object NodeList item

Comment: added code sample how to get list of selected ID

Comment: if my answer helps you you can mark it as correct) I belive it helps))